# Find Count of Column based on the Max of Another Column in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I've table A with three columns: `Dates`, `A_ID`, and `B_ID`. Each date there are multiple `A_ID` and each `A_ID` contains multiple `B_ID`.

```
Dates            A_ID    B_ID
4/5/2018         01245   DEF
4/5/2018         12345   ABC
4/6/2018         42345   WER
4/7/2018         52345   ABC
4/7/2018         67700   XCV
```

First of all I want to display the `Distinct_Date` as in just show one date. Second, I want the count of total `B_ID` for each date but since `B_ID` can be in multiple `A_ID` I want to count based on the `MAX` of `A_ID`. 
For example on `4/5/2018` count for `B_ID` is one (DEF), `4/6/2018` is one (WER), and on `4/7/2018` the `A_ID` `52345` is greater than the one in `4/5/2018` so I would only count the `4/7/2018` `B_ID`'s `ABC` as one. And count the `B_ID` `XCV` as another count for that date. So the result would look like the below table.

```
Distinct_Dates   Count_B_ID
4/5/2018         1
4/6/2018         1
4/7/2018         2
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the max date per b_id and aggregate on dates. To avoid missing dates, left join` on all the distinct dates after counting.

```
select d.date,coalesce(cnt,0)
from (select distinct date from tbl) d
left join (select dt,count(distinct b_id) as cnt
           from (select b_id,max(date) as dt
                 from tbl  
                 group by b_id
                ) t
           group by dt
          ) t on t.dt=d.date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Dates, Count(*)
FROM 
 (
   SELECT Dates, A_ID, B_ID
   FROM tab
   QUALIFY 
      Row_Number() -- return the row with the higest A_ID for each B_ID,
      Over(PARTITION BY B_ID
           ORDER BY A_ID DESC) = 1
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: This answer could do with an explanation.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: What should I explain further than *return the row with the higest A_ID for each B_ID*, which is the only tricky part?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need two `group by` :

```
select Distinct_Dates, count(*) as Count_B_ID
from (select b_id, max(dates) as Distinct_Dates 
      from table
      group by b_id
     ) tt
group by Distinct_Dates;
```